# Text/View is not hiding in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, view, show-hide

I am trying to hiding the Text/View based on flag value in my react native.
But, Its not hiding.

Here is my code

> Class.js file

```
     componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          isHidden: true
        });
      }

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isHidden: false,
    };
      }

render() {
    console.log('renderer');
    const { isHidden } = this.state;
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              //some other objects showing
                  <Text style={styles.Text} hide={isHidden}>
                    Date is Jan 02
                  </Text>
                //some other objects showing
                  <Text style={styles.Text} hide={isHidden}>
              </View>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
```

But, Its not hiding even the flag value is true.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a React Native developer, however, from the [looks of the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text) the `Text` component does not have a `hide` prop. If you were to approach this from a standard React point-of-view, you would either add the appropriate functionality to your component (which I presume you cannot do), or change your render method:

```
class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {!this.state.isHidden && <Text style={styles.text}>Exciting copy...</Text>}
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this helps. React does not have any hide attribute so you have to condtionally render the text field on the basis of isHidden variable

```
 (!isHidden)?<Text style={styles.Text}>Date is Jan 02</Text>: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Native [Text](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text) doesn't have a hide prop. You can get the desired effect this way `{!this.state.isHidden}<Text>....</Text>`

I took a look at your code and I have some remarks.

> It's adviced always to `Prevent usage of setState in componentDidMount (no-did-mount-set-state)`. Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but it is guaranteed to flush during the same tick. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state.

So it causes no visible side-effects.

> Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. So Unless you are, doing `server-rendering`, anything that requires a browser environment *must* go in `componentDidMount`, since that runs client-only, but `componentWillMount` runs on both client and server.